# *ngFor object attribute undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

I'm starting on Angular 2 coming from Angular 1, and I can't figure how to use ngFor on an object's attribute.
`this.myVar` is defined upon the result of an HTTP request, which defines the `attr` attribute.

Here's my code:

```
# my_page.ts
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MyService} from '../../services/my_service';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/my_page/my_page.html',
  providers: [MyService]
})


export class MyPage {
  public myVar;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.fetch().subscribe(
      data => this.myVar = data
    );
  }
}

# my_page.html
<div *ngFor="#item of myVar.attr">
</div>
```

And this is the error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined in [myVar.attr in ...]

Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because initially till `ajax` gets completed `myVar` doesn't have any value in it & while evaluating expression of `ngFor`, it tries to access `attr` property of undefined object. Do use [`Elvis operator`][1], by having `?` it will check if object defined, if it is defined then then only it evaluate `attr` property from it.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myVar?.attr"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Do you know if it's possible to use something like this for an Array position? Like `myVar?[0]`

Comment: @akz92 you can do that.. but why you wanted to do it. as you each element of collection is being catch by `ngFor`

Comment: I'm just curious :) I've never heard of this operator before